# Rephrasing a question: Help needed

Tags: discussion

This is about this [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/11039/wording-problem-reply-to-an-invitation)

As suggested by Neil Fein, I am asking this on Meta.

Any suggestions on how to edit the question so that it is less of an etiquette question and more of a writing question (and also takes care of the fact that it doesn't become a question about what to write).

The problem, as I see it, is that writing a reply to an invitation (such as the one under consideration) is closely linked to socio-cultural practices and etiquettes. It does not have a clear cut answer as over a question which might ask for guidelines on how to write a particular kind of content.

If the question is reframed to be something like *How to write a reply to wedding invitation*, then the text quoted in the question would suffice as the answer. The question is more about specific case(s) under this broader question which also involves aspects like *what would be the best thing to do under such a condition* which might lead to opinions and also people giving general answers such as [this](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/11046/5909).

The goal of asking the question is not to seek reasons as to why one should write a particular kind of reply and why one should seek to make it more convenient for the bride/groom/whoever. Nor am I seeking answers that tell me "use your common sense". I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place then.

Again, rephrasing the question to be something like *Guidelines for writing replies to an invitation* will also not suffice.

Any suggestions on how to edit this question? Thanks a lot!